# Prevent apps from being suspended

Tags: applications, 7.0-nougat, termux

I run `sshd` in a `Termux` window as my main means of accessing files on my Galaxy S7.  This works fairly well, except that I seem to have to re-run `sshd` rather frequently.  I suspect that this is because `Termux` is getting suspended by the OS.  I'm fairly certain that I've told it not to do so, but it seems to be happening anyway.  Using [these instructions](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/android-basics-disable-doze-app-standby-for-individual-apps-0168960/), which seem to be out of date for Nougat, as a rough guide, I've navigated to **Settings -> Device maintenance -> Battery -> Unmonitored apps**; `Termux` appears in this list of "apps that will not be recommended to be put to sleep."  However, after using other apps, `Termux` is not always present in the list of apps that appears when I hit the, erm, "windows" button at the bottom left corner of the phone, and as mentioned above, I frequently have to open a `Termux` window and run `sshd` again.

Is there something else I need to do to prevent `Termux` (and/or other apps) from being suspended?